# How to prevent await to be executed?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My code below executes a task one at a time.

```
await App.TodoManager.SyncUserClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.UpdateContacts(contact);
await App.TodoManager.SyncContactsClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncContactsMedia1ClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncContactsMedia2ClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncContactsMedia3ClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncContactsMedia4ClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncRetailerOutletClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.UpdateCAF(contact);
await App.TodoManager.SyncCAFClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncCAFMedia1ClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncCAFMedia2ClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncCAFMedia3ClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncCAFMedia4ClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncCAFActivityClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncEmailRecipientClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncUserServerUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncSystemSerialServerUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncContactsServerUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncRetailerOutletServerUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncProvinceServerUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncTownServerUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.SyncUserLogsClientUpdate(host, database, ipaddress, contact, SyncStatus);
await App.TodoManager.OnSyncComplete(host, database, ipaddress, contact);
```

My problem is this, each of this task have a internet connection checker meaning it will check whether the device have internet connection when the app detects that the device doesn't have an internet connection it will display a display alert prompting the user. When the user chose not to retry he/she will be redirected to my mainpage. Here comes the problem, for example on my first task (**SyncUserClientUpdate**) detects that there is no connection and the user chose not to retry, he/she will be redirected but when getting to the mainpage the display alert of the other Task will appear and the same thing will happen when the user chose not to retry he/she will redirected to the mainpage over and over until the last function has been executed. How can I stop other Task when I chose not to retry?

```
public async Task SyncUserClientUpdate(string host, string database, string domain, string contact, Action<string>SyncStatus)
    {
        SyncStatus("Initiating Client Update User Sync");
        SyncStatus("Checking Connection To Server");

        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
            var conn = db.GetConnection();

            string apifile = "sync-user-client-update-api.php";

            SyncStatus("Checking Data From Local Database");

            var datachanges = conn.QueryAsync<UserTable>("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE ContactID = ? AND LastUpdated > LastSync AND Deleted != '1'", contact);
            var changesresultCount = datachanges.Result.Count;

            if (changesresultCount > 0)
            {
                int clientupdate = 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < changesresultCount; i++)
                {
                    SyncStatus("Sending user changes to server " + clientupdate + " out of " + changesresultCount);

                    var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://" + domain + "/TBSApi/" + apifile + "?Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database, string.Empty));

                    try
                    {
                        var result = datachanges.Result[i];
                        var userid = result.UserID;
                        var usrpassword = result.UsrPassword;
                        var usertypeid = result.UserTypeID;
                        var userstatus = result.UserStatus;
                        var lastsync = DateTime.Parse(current_datetime);
                        var lastupdated = result.LastUpdated;
                        var deleted = result.Deleted;

                        JObject json = new JObject
                        {
                            { "UserID", userid },
                            { "UsrPassword", usrpassword },
                            { "ContactID", contact },
                            { "UserTypeID", usertypeid },
                            { "UserStatus", userstatus },
                            { "LastUpdated", lastupdated },
                            { "Deleted", deleted }
                        };

                        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType));

                        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                            {
                                var dataresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ServerMessage>>(content, settings);

                                var dataitem = dataresult[0];
                                var datamessage = dataitem.Message;

                                if (datamessage.Equals("Inserted"))
                                {
                                    await conn.QueryAsync<UserTable>("UPDATE tblUsers SET LastSync = ? WHERE ContactID = ?", DateTime.Parse(current_datetime), contact);

                                    clientupdate++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Client Update User Sync Error", "Syncing failed.\n\n Error:\n\n" + datamessage + "\n\n Do you want to retry?", "Yes", "No");

                                    if (retry)
                                    {
                                        await SyncUserClientUpdate(host, database, domain, contact, SyncStatus);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainMenu(host, database, contact, domain));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Client Update User Sync Error", "Syncing failed. Status Code:\n\n" + response.StatusCode, "Yes", "No");

                            if (retry)
                            {
                                await SyncUserClientUpdate(host, database, domain, contact, SyncStatus);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainMenu(host, database, contact, domain));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
                        var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Client Update User Sync Error", "Syncing failed.\n\n Error:\n\n" + ex.Message, "Yes", "No");

                        if (retry)
                        {
                            await SyncUserClientUpdate(host, database, domain, contact, SyncStatus);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainMenu(host, database, contact, domain));
                        }
                    }
                }

                var logType = "App Log";
                var log = "Sent client updates to the server (<b>User</b>)  <br/>" + "App Version: <b>" + Constants.appversion + "</b><br/> Device ID: <b>" + Constants.deviceID + "</b>";
                int logdeleted = 0;

                await Save_Logs(contact, logType, log, database, logdeleted);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Client Update User Sync Error", "Syncing failed. Please connect to the internet to sync your data. Do you want to retry?", "Yes", "No");

            if (retry)
            {
                await SyncUserClientUpdate(host, database, domain, contact, SyncStatus);
            }
            else
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainMenu(host, database, contact, domain));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can simply `throw` (e.g. `InvalidOperationException`) when user interrupts, because, well, its error. The caller should catch it.

Comment: @Sinatr can you show me how?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called `CancellationToken` for async `Tasks`

You can check this awesome blog by Stephen [@Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/) blogs

Basically, you define a cancellation token

```
CancellationToken token = …;
```

Then execute it with cancellation

```
 public static async Task<T> WithCancellation<T>( 
 this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{ 
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(); 
using(cancellationToken.Register( 
            s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true), tcs)) 
    if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task)) 
        throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken); 
return await task; 
}
```

Also display alert returns a boolean by default so your if statement can look something like below you do not need the equals operation.

```
if (retry)
{..}
```

Comment: Can you pattern that in my code? so I can have the gist of it

Comment: Basically, you need to apply this token to the main task that invokes all this for your use case, if you read the blog its soo simple you actually do not need me!!!

Comment: I really do not know your code to tell you how exactly to do it but the blog tells you everything!! I mean I am sure you will be able to do it. Also, I am busy right now

Comment: @lootverge, you will have to pass cancellation token into all tasks and all tasks have to check at start if it was already canceled and return immediately.

Comment: @Sinatr I update my question I included a sample code for my tasks

Answer (score 0):

Using `await` allows you to catch task exceptions ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch#example-2)):

> To catch an exception that an async task throws, place the await expression in a try block, and catch the exception in a catch block

If either of task will `throw`, then the following up tasks will not run.

```
try
{
    await Task1();
    await Task2();
    ...
}
catch(SomeException e) { ... }
```

All you need is to

```
throw new SomeException(...)
```

inside the method which is called by task to confirm user action and user chooses to cancel.

One may argue: "Do not use exceptions for flow control". True, but in case if user can interrupt *normal flow*, it's totally accepted, because user interrupting program flow is *exceptional* case, it will not occurs normally, it is an *exception*.

Good candidate is `InvalidOperationException`, but you may want to create custom exception (`UserInterruptException`) to catch "user interrupt" reason more reliable.

Comment: It catches the exception but the task still executes

Comment: *"still executes"* ? Do you already use `Task.WhenAny` from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576249/1997232) or what? The task which throws will finish and the program will continue from `catch`, so which task precisely is still executes?

Comment: No, because I dont know how to proceed

Comment: @lootverge  You can check this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch